# replace the NaN value zero after an operation with arrays

Tags: python

how can I replace the NaN value in an array, zero if an operation is performed such that as a result instead of the NaN value is zero operations as

0 / 0 = NaN can be replaced by 0

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you have Python 2.6 you have the [`math.isnan()`](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.isnan) function to find `NaN` values.

With this we can use a list comprehension to replace the `NaN` values in a list as follows:

```
import math
mylist = [0 if math.isnan(x) else x for x in mylist]
```

If you have Python 2.5 we can use the `NaN != NaN` trick from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944700/how-to-check-for-nan-in-python) so you do this:

```
mylist = [0 if x != x else x for x in mylist]
```

Comment: so will the package numpy
>>> from numpy import *

Answer (score 6):

```
import numpy
a=numpy.array([1,2,3,'NaN',4])
s=numpy.isnan(a)
a[s]=0.0
```

Answer (score 3):

There is also a pandas solution to this.

```py
import pandas as pd

mylist = [2.3, pd.NA, 1.1, 0.7]
mylist = [0 if pd.isna(x) else x for x in mylist]
```

Answer (score 0):

import numpy

alpha = numpy.array([1,2,3,numpy.nan,4])

n = numpy.nan_to_num(alpha)

print(n)

output : array([1., 2., 3., 0., 4.])

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.