# Is it possible to set a number to NaN or infinity?

Tags: python, numeric, nan, infinite

Is it possible to set an element of an array to `NaN` in Python?

Additionally, is it possible to set a variable to +/- infinity? If so, is there any function to check whether a number is infinity or not?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944700/ tells you how to check for NaN. For Inf and -Inf you can test with == but that doesn't work for NaN because of the IEEE754 rules for NaN.

Answer (score 307, accepted):

Cast from string using `float()`:

```
>>> float('NaN')
nan
>>> float('Inf')
inf
>>> -float('Inf')
-inf
>>> float('Inf') == float('Inf')
True
>>> float('Inf') == 1
False
```

Comment: That will teach me not to jump in with a quip before reading the question over a second time!! Sorry! That said, it wouldn't hurt to say so all the same because it's an easy trap to fall into,  NaN != NaN

Comment: also note: >>> float('Inf')-float('Inf')  ===>
nan

Comment: note:```float('Inf')*0``` and ```float('Inf')/float('Inf')``` ==> nan. and also ```float('Inf')*-1``` ==> -inf

Answer (score 83):

Yes, you can use [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/) for that.

```
import numpy as np
a = arange(3,dtype=float)

a[0] = np.nan
a[1] = np.inf
a[2] = -np.inf

a # is now [nan,inf,-inf]

np.isnan(a[0]) # True
np.isinf(a[1]) # True
np.isinf(a[2]) # True
```

Comment: On python >= 2.6, you can just use `math.isnan()` and `math.isinf()`

Comment: `numpy` is quite a heavy import if all you want is `NaN` or `inf`

Comment: If all you need is `NaN` or `Inf`, one could `from numpy import nan, inf` which has existed since this question was raised.

Answer (score 55):

> Is it possible to set a number to NaN or infinity?

Yes, in fact there are several ways. A few work without any imports, while others require `import`, however for this answer I'll limit the libraries in the overview to standard-library and NumPy (which isn't standard-library but a very common third-party library).

The following table summarizes the ways how one can create a not-a-number or a positive or negative infinity `float`:

```
╒══════════╤══════════════╤════════════════════╤════════════════════╕
│   result │ NaN          │ Infinity           │ -Infinity          │
│ module   │              │                    │                    │
╞══════════╪══════════════╪════════════════════╪════════════════════╡
│ built-in │ float("nan") │ float("inf")       │ -float("inf")      │
│          │              │ float("infinity")  │ -float("infinity") │
│          │              │ float("+inf")      │ float("-inf")      │
│          │              │ float("+infinity") │ float("-infinity") │
├──────────┼──────────────┼────────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│ math     │ math.nan     │ math.inf           │ -math.inf          │
├──────────┼──────────────┼────────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│ cmath    │ cmath.nan    │ cmath.inf          │ -cmath.inf         │
├──────────┼──────────────┼────────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│ numpy    │ numpy.nan    │ numpy.PINF         │ numpy.NINF         │
│          │ numpy.NaN    │ numpy.inf          │ -numpy.inf         │
│          │ numpy.NAN    │ numpy.infty        │ -numpy.infty       │
│          │              │ numpy.Inf          │ -numpy.Inf         │
│          │              │ numpy.Infinity     │ -numpy.Infinity    │
╘══════════╧══════════════╧════════════════════╧════════════════════╛
```

A couple remarks to the table:

- The `float` constructor is actually case-insensitive, so you can also use `float("NaN")` or `float("InFiNiTy")`.
- The `cmath` and `numpy` constants return plain Python `float` objects.
- The `numpy.NINF` is actually the only constant I know of that doesn't require the `-`.
- It is possible to create complex NaN and Infinity with `complex` and `cmath`:

  ```
  ╒══════════╤════════════════╤═════════════════╤═════════════════════╤══════════════════════╕
  │   result │ NaN+0j         │ 0+NaNj          │ Inf+0j              │ 0+Infj               │
  │ module   │                │                 │                     │                      │
  ╞══════════╪════════════════╪═════════════════╪═════════════════════╪══════════════════════╡
  │ built-in │ complex("nan") │ complex("nanj") │ complex("inf")      │ complex("infj")      │
  │          │                │                 │ complex("infinity") │ complex("infinityj") │
  ├──────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────┼─────────────────────┼──────────────────────┤
  │ cmath    │ cmath.nan ¹    │ cmath.nanj      │ cmath.inf ¹         │ cmath.infj           │
  ╘══════════╧════════════════╧═════════════════╧═════════════════════╧══════════════════════╛
  ```

  The options with ¹ return a plain `float`, not a `complex`.

> is there any function to check whether a number is infinity or not?

Yes there is - in fact there are several functions for NaN, Infinity, and neither Nan nor Inf. However these predefined functions are not built-in, they always require an `import`:

```
╒══════════╤═════════════╤════════════════╤════════════════════╕
│      for │ NaN         │ Infinity or    │ not NaN and        │
│          │             │ -Infinity      │ not Infinity and   │
│ module   │             │                │ not -Infinity      │
╞══════════╪═════════════╪════════════════╪════════════════════╡
│ math     │ math.isnan  │ math.isinf     │ math.isfinite      │
├──────────┼─────────────┼────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│ cmath    │ cmath.isnan │ cmath.isinf    │ cmath.isfinite     │
├──────────┼─────────────┼────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│ numpy    │ numpy.isnan │ numpy.isinf    │ numpy.isfinite     │
╘══════════╧═════════════╧════════════════╧════════════════════╛
```

Again a couple of remarks:

- The `cmath` and `numpy` functions also work for complex objects, they will check if either real or imaginary part is NaN or Infinity.
- The `numpy` functions also work for `numpy` arrays and everything that can be converted to one (like lists, tuple, etc.)
- There are also functions that explicitly check for positive and negative infinity in NumPy: `numpy.isposinf` and `numpy.isneginf`.
- Pandas offers two additional functions to check for `NaN`: [`pandas.isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.isna.html#pandas.isna) and [`pandas.isnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.isnull.html#pandas.isnull) (but not only NaN, it matches also `None` and `NaT`)
- Even though there are no built-in functions, it would be easy to create them yourself (I neglected type checking and documentation here):

  ```
  def isnan(value):
      return value != value  # NaN is not equal to anything, not even itself

  infinity = float("infinity")

  def isinf(value):
      return abs(value) == infinity 

  def isfinite(value):
      return not (isnan(value) or isinf(value))
  ```

To summarize the expected results for these functions (assuming the input is a float):

```
╒════════════════╤═══════╤════════════╤═════════════╤══════════════════╕
│          input │ NaN   │ Infinity   │ -Infinity   │ something else   │
│ function       │       │            │             │                  │
╞════════════════╪═══════╪════════════╪═════════════╪══════════════════╡
│ isnan          │ True  │ False      │ False       │ False            │
├────────────────┼───────┼────────────┼─────────────┼──────────────────┤
│ isinf          │ False │ True       │ True        │ False            │
├────────────────┼───────┼────────────┼─────────────┼──────────────────┤
│ isfinite       │ False │ False      │ False       │ True             │
╘════════════════╧═══════╧════════════╧═════════════╧══════════════════╛
```

> Is it possible to set an element of an array to NaN in Python?

In a list it's no problem, you can always include NaN (or Infinity) there:

```
>>> [math.nan, math.inf, -math.inf, 1]  # python list
[nan, inf, -inf, 1]
```

However if you want to include it in an `array` (for example `array.array` or `numpy.array`) then the type of the array **must** be `float` or `complex` because otherwise it will try to downcast it to the arrays type!

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> float_numpy_array = np.array([0., 0., 0.], dtype=float)
>>> float_numpy_array[0] = float("nan")
>>> float_numpy_array
array([nan,  0.,  0.])

>>> import array
>>> float_array = array.array('d', [0, 0, 0])
>>> float_array[0] = float("nan")
>>> float_array
array('d', [nan, 0.0, 0.0])

>>> integer_numpy_array = np.array([0, 0, 0], dtype=int)
>>> integer_numpy_array[0] = float("nan")
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

Comment: Note: `math.isnan` does not work with complex numbers. Use `math.isnan(x.real) or math.isnan(x.imag)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

When using Python 2.4, try

```
inf = float("9e999")
nan = inf - inf
```

I am facing the issue when I was porting the simplejson to an embedded device which running the Python 2.4, `float("9e999")` fixed it. Don't use `inf = 9e999`, you need convert it from string.
`-inf` gives the `-Infinity`.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can calculate them

```
Python 3.9 on Windows 10
>>> import sys
>>> Inf = sys.float_info.max * 10
>>> Inf
inf
>>> NaN = Inf - Inf
>>> NaN
nan
```