# Adding NaN's in python variable?

Tags: python

If I have a variable with missings, how do I assign them as NaNs in python?

I've tried the following but it's returning an empty dataframe:

```
data_2017_18.income=np.nan
```

Much appreciated.

Comment: Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5438756/10732434) from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438745/is-it-possible-to-set-a-number-to-nan-or-infinity).

Comment: Please clarify your question, add a [mre]. Are you working with `pandas`? If so, what do you want to achieve, what to you want to do with column 'income'?

Comment: I'm looking to give all of the cases that have no data the value of 'NaN'. I did have a look at the above answer but it doesn't seem to be relevant?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `float("nan")` to get a "not a number" (NaN) value.

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand this - I'm hoping to assign all the cases with no value in the variable as NaN ?