# Python: how to return NaN if name doesn't exist in index?

Tags: python, indexing, nan

Python experts,

Is there a way to get NaN if a name doesn't not exist in the index? Say I pass in a list to retrieve the data Series.  Currently, if I do `df[myindex]` directly, for those names non-existent in the index, I will get errors like:

> KeyError: "['SAL_YIELD_NTM'] not in index"

I'd like to get the normal results back but put Nan for those non-existent index names.  Is there a way for this in Python?

Thanks much!

Comment: Just check if the key exists on the data structure (list or dictionary). If it doesn't, just return `float("NaN")` to get the Not a Number value. By the way, it is already answered here how you can get / assign this value: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438745/is-it-possible-to-set-a-number-to-nan-or-infinity

Comment: Lots of ways, e.g. `df.get(myindex, float('NaN'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `try` to get the key, and if an error is raised handle it however you want:

```
try:
    my_value = df[myindex]
except KeyError as e:
    my_value = "NaN"
```

If `df` is a dictionary, you can use the `get` method which can be provided with a default value if the key is not found:

```
my_value = df.get(myindex, "NaN")
```