# creating lists from text file using pandas in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

I have a text file (data.txt) like below:

```
name height  weight
    A   15.5    55.7
    B   18.9    51.6
    C   17.4    67.3
    D   11.4    34.5
    E   23.4    92.1
```

I want to make list in python for each column using pandas.

```
import pandas
with open (pandas.read_csv('data.txt')) as df:
    name= df.icol(0)
    height= df.icol(1)
    weight= df.icol(2)
    print (name)
    print (height)
    print (weight)
```

I also want to avoid the headers (name, height, weight) from the list.

print (df) provides as follows:

```
name\theight\tweight
0        A\t15.5\t55.7
1        B\t18.9\t51.6
2        C\t17.4\t67.3
3        D\t11.4\t34.5
4        E\t23.4\t92.1
```

Comment: did you not ask this same question with an account named lisa?

Comment: ``read_csv`` expects commas by default, not tabs, so it has failed to parse your data into columns. Try again with ``read_csv('data.txt', delim_whitespace=True)``.

Comment: But... *why* would you want these as lists??

Comment: @andy for further computation

Comment: Exactly... you don't want to be using lists for that!!

Comment: @andy yes, i want to be using lists

Comment: Well, you're wrong... you should be doing your analysis in \*pandas\*, that's what it's there for!

Comment: @andy please suggest me simplest and easiest way for that then.

Comment: You haven't even said what computation you want do... http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html

Comment: @andy ather than talking about further computation, can you provide me alternative solution for above problem with out using pandas and in a very simplest form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not clear why you want to use pandas because you haven't said why you want them specifically in a list, so here is a solution using `csv`:

```
import csv

with open('data.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='\t')
    rows = list(reader)
```

Now `rows` is a list of dictionaries, each with a header that represents your rows; to get each of your columns:

```
names = [i['name'] for i in rows]
heights = [float(i['height']) if i['height'] else 0.0 for i in rows]
weights = [float(i['weight']) if i['weight'] else 0.0 for i in rows]
```

Comment: @ burhan actually, i wanted to use pandas thinking that will simplify the program. but pandas did not work as i thought. so now considering your solution too.

Comment: It is often best to ask for help with the _problem_ and not the _solution to the problem_. This is often referred to the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @ burhan i got error with your code                                      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\PYTHON\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    reader = csv.DictReader(delimiter='\t')
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: still the lists of height and weight are in strings, want to get in floats

Comment: See the updated answer. I added a default value of 0.0 to heights and weights in case they were blank in the file (otherwise you'd get a TypeError exception).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('data.txt')
# Assuming there's a columns with the headers 'name', 'height', 'weight'
name = list(df['name'])
height = list(df['height'])
weight = list(df['weight'])
print name
print height
print weight
```

Figured this might work after playing with [this example](http://www.econpy.org/tutorials/general/csv-pandas-dataframe) and looking at the docs for [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html)

If you want to be a bit more dynamic with headers you can do

```
for k in df.keys():
    l = list(df[k])
    print l
```

which will iterate over all columns and create lists for them.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a Series (e.g., a column of a DataFrame) to an ordinary Python list of values without the header, use the Series method `tolist()`.

```
In [9]: df
Out[9]: 
  name  height  weight
0    A    15.5    55.7
1    B    18.9    51.6
2    C    17.4    67.3
3    D    11.4    34.5
4    E    23.4    92.1

In [10]: name, height, weight = [df[col].tolist() for col in df]

In [11]: name
Out[11]: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```

and so on.

Comment: my df output looks like yours above, but when I try `df['name'].tolist()` I get a `KeyError: u'no item named name'` message.

Comment: Would you post the output of ``df`` exactly? I suspect your column names have not loaded correctly.

Comment: Yeah, Andy is totally right here. Look at [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) to learn more.

Comment: `df = pandas.read_csv("pandas_test.txt", sep=r"\s+")` was needed to handle the leading white space in example file.

Answer (score 0):

Because the example text file above has leading white space in the first column, the following must be used to prevent incorrect table importing:

```
df = pandas.read_csv("pandas_test.txt", sep=r"\s+")
```