# All operations that will result in nan values(python)

Tags: python, numpy, nan

This may be a simple question but i could not get all the answers in one place, so any help and answer are welcome :) . I am trying to debug a program, But then I realize I don't know what are all the possible operation that may result in a NAN value in python. so here is the question what are all the possible operations that will result in a nan value in python specifically numpy matrices?

An example will be like

```
x=float('nan')
x=x+x
print x
```

results in

```
nan
```

Comment: `NaN` stands for *not a number*. Any computation that doesn't make sense is `NaN`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/944733/860196

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In numpy land you often get `nan`s for illegal mathematical operations. Consider

```
>>> from math import asin
>>> asin(1.1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: math domain error
```

Similar operation in numpy yields a nan:

```
>>> from numpy import arcsin
>>> arcsin(1.1)
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in arcsin
nan
```

Notice that by (python's) default you only get a warning once.

When debugging, look for illegal operations, esp domain errors: divisions by zero, square roots of negative numbers etc.

A second major source of nans is indeterminate expressions of the form inf/inf, 0/0, 0*inf and so on.

Lastly, since nans are sticky (once you have a first nan in an expression, it propagates), when debugging you typically need to find *the first* operation which goes haywire.

Answer (score 2):

NaNs are part of the IEEE 754 standards. Operation like but not limited to inf * 0, inf / inf or any operation involving a NaN, e.g. nan * 1, return a NaN.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985