# Python: how to check a variable is a meaningful numerical type

Tags: python, numpy, math

In python, how can I check a variable is a numerical type and has a meaningful value?

Here I mean by 'numerical type' those like `int`, `float`, and `complex` with all different bit length, and by 'meaningful value' that it is not `nan` or any other special values that can not be used for further computation.

(I guess this is such a common issue and there must be a duplicate question, but I did not find one after a quick search. Please let me know if there is a duplicate.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944700/how-to-check-for-nan-in-python

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float-in-python and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python

Comment: Please consider [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/154156/8747). Just say no.

Comment: @Will I found in the post you referred to that the answer by DaveTheScientist is helpful.

Comment: @Robᵩ Unfortunately I think I can't defend the principle you referred to in my context because `float('nan') < 1.0e-12` (for example) does not behave in the way I want. I want it to stop the execution or at least to be evaluated as `False`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 2.x and 3.x

```
import math
import numbers

def is_numerical(x):
    return isinstance(x, numbers.Number) and not isinstance(x, bool) and not math.isnan(abs(n)) and math.isfinite(abs(n))
```

Reason for the distinction is because Python 3 merged the `long` and `int` types into just `int`.

Edit: Added upon answer below using `numbers.Number` to exclude booleans.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from math import isnan
>>> isnan(float('nan'))
True
>>> isnan(1j.real)
False
>>> isnan(1j.imag)
False
```

Integers can never be NaNs.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how thorough you want to be. Besides the builtin types (`complex`, `float`, and `int`) there are also other types that are considered numbers in python. For instance: [`fractions.Fraction`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html), [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html), and even `bool` can act as a number. Then you get external libraries that have their own numeric types. By far the biggest is [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/). With `numpy` some of its types will succeed `isinstance` checks, and other will not. For instance: `isinstance(numpy.float64(10), float)` is true, but `isinstance(numpy.float32(10), float)` is not.
On top of all this you could even have a user defined class that acts like a number.

Python does provide one way of getting around this -- the [`numbers`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html) module. It provides several abstract types that represent different types of numbers. Any class that implements numeric functionality can register itself as being compatible with the relevant types. `numbers.Number` is the most basic, and therefore the one you're looking for. All you have to do is use it  in your `isinstance` checks. eg.

```
from numbers import Number
from decimal import Decimal
from fractions import Fraction
import numpy

assert isinstance(1, Number)
assert isinstance(1.5, Number)  
assert isinstance(1+5j, Number)  
assert isinstance(True, Number)

assert isinstance(Decimal("1.23"), Number)
assert isinstance(Fraction(1, 2), Number)

assert isinstance(numpy.float64(10), Number)
assert isinstance(numpy.float32(10), Number)
assert isinstance(numpy.int32(10), Number)
assert isinstance(numpy.uint32(10), Number)
```

That still leaves us with the problem about whether the object is actually a number, rather than "not a number". The [`math.isnan`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isnan) function is good for this, but it requires that the number be convertible to a float (which not all numbers are). The big problem here is the `complex` type. There are a few ways around this: additional `isinstance` checks (but that comes with its own headaches), using [`abs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs), or testing for equality.

`abs` can be used on every numeric type (that I can think of). For most numbers it returns the positive version of the number, but for complex numbers it returns its magnitude (a float). So now we can do  that `isnan` check. `nan` is also a special number in that it is the only number that is not equal to itself.

This means your final check might look like:

```
import math
import numbers

def number_is_not_nan(n):
    return isinstance(n, numbers.Number) and not math.isnan(abs(n))

def number_is_finite(n):
    return isinstance(n, numbers.Number) and not math.isfinite(abs(n))
```

Answer (score -1):

I am answering to my own question. This is based on [Seth Michael Larson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39396169/883431)
and [DaveTheScientist's answer for another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12588878/883431). Considering that I need to be careful for `float('inf')` and `float('-inf')` as well as `float('nan')`, and that the passed argument `x` may be complex, I ended up writing the following function for the check.

```
def is_a_meaningful_number(x):
    import math
    if sys.version_info >= (3, 0, 0):
        NUMERIC_TYPES = (int, complex, float)
    else:
        NUMERIC_TYPES = (int, long, complex, float)
    return isinstance(x, NUMERIC_TYPES) and float('-inf') < abs(x) < float('inf')
```