# Difference between nan and 'nan' in Python

Tags: python, numpy, nan

I have two lists

```
a = ['E300' 'E407' 'nan' 'nan' 'nan' 'nan' 'nan' 'nan' 'nan' 'nan' ]
b = [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
```

I wanted to remove nan from the lists. So I used this on list 'a' and 'b'

```
a = [x for x in a if x != 'nan']
b = [x for x in b if x != 'nan']
```

So it works fine for list 'a' because I think it was taking 'nan' as a string but not with list b. How can I remove those nan from list b. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `nan` is a number, `'nan'` is a string.

Comment: It's the same as the difference between `123` and `'123'`

Comment: @MorganThrapp NaN is not equal to itself (no foolin'!) so that won't work.

Comment: nan is not in string quotes so it is not recognized by the system i think. It is throwing error

Comment: What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: `nan` is a [bit pattern](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~eedwards/compsys/float/nan.html) with a specific meaning to floating point operations. `'nan'` is a string with maybe some meaning to human eyes...

Comment: Dup of [How to check for NaN in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/944700/2800918)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you don't put it in quotes, `nan` is a number (it's a special number used to represent a nonexistent result, called "Not a Number"). It's so special that it doesn't even equal itself. Use `math.isnan` or `numpy.isnan` to test if a number is `nan`

```
b = [x for x in b if not math.isnan(x)]
```

Comment: This is the perfect answer if you add that `nan` has signal properties to floating point operations in the IEEE specifications...

Comment: @dawg I'm not sure how that's relevant to the question of how to remove it from the list.

Comment: +1 for giving this method. I am a newbie in python too. I wonder since `nan` comes from `numpy`, why doesn't `numpy` provides a method for checking the `nan`, something like `pandas.isnull()` does. Any idea?

Comment: when use `!`, do you mean `not`?

Comment: @Psidom [numpy.isnan](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html)

Comment: Ah. shame on me. Just didn't know that before.

Comment: @HaifengZhang Thanks. I don't use Python regularly enough to remember some of its differences from other languages.

Answer (score 1):

`'nan'` is a string, but `nan` is a floating-point number.  Which is funny, because "nan" stands for [Not A Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN), but that's really what it is:

```
>>> type(nan)
<class 'float'>
```

`nan` has a number of tricky properties, and one of the trickiest is that it compares unequal to *everything*, *including itself*.  You have to use a special function to check for it, [`math.isnan`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isnan).

```
>>> b
[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
>>> [x for x in b if x != nan]
[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
>>> [x for x in b if not math.isnan(x)]
[]
```

Note: Python does not define a built-in constant `nan`, even though the `repr` of a NaN value is `nan`.  (Contrast `True`, `False`, `None`, etc.)  3.5 and later have [`math.nan`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.nan), but before that you have to say `float('nan')`.

Comment: Actually `nan`, `inf` and `-inf`. are floating-point values but not floating-point numbers .

Comment: @Goyo A mathematician would agree with you, but a programming language designer wouldn't.  In Python, a floating-point number is any value with type `float`, and `nan` and `±inf` are included.

Comment: You are right, in Python, all instances of `float` are called numbers. I assumed incorrectly that the language specification would make a difference. Out of curiosity I checked IEEE-758-2008 (the last revision of the standard that languages are expected to follow... well, more or less) and it says that NaNs are not floating-point numbers but infinities are.

Answer (score 0):

'nan' is a string

nan is Not A number, you can check it by method `math.isnan()`

```
>>> nan=float('nan')
>>> math.isnan(nan)
True
```

In your case:

```
b = [x for x in b if not math.isnan(x)]
```