# Replacing NaN with 0 in Python

Tags: python, nan

I have some data that is missing values here and there. I need to replace the NaN with zeros, as I do mathematical operations with those elements in the list named `ls`. I tried a list comprehension, but did not work:

```
[0 if i==None else i for i in ls]
```

Thanks for help/suggestions!

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944700/how-to-check-for-nan-in-python  math.isnan(...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check for NaN in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944700/how-to-check-for-nan-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
import math
[0 if math.isnan(i) else i for i in ls]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working either. The NaN values are still there in the list.

Comment: Are you sure they are numerical types and not strings?

Comment: Thank you! - you are right -  as I was working late, I forgot to check if they are "System.Double" (IronPython) or strings. I ended up changing the entire list to strings, then convert back to numbers. However IronPython didn't like isnan, but it worked with None as the comprehension:       [0 if i==None else i for i in ls]

Answer (score -2):

Try the following:

```
from numpy import isnan

[0 if isnan(i) else i for i in ls]
```

Comment: Thanks - but I forgot to mention: I'm stuck with IronPython on this one, so I cannot use numpy.

Comment: Ah, okay. Max's answer is then your best bet.