# How to compare one value with 'NaN' in if statement: Python 3.5.2 | Anaconda 4.1.0 (64 bit) For example: a!=Nan where a is either a float value

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

```
for r in range(65000):
    for c in range(8):
        if df1.iloc[r,c] != NaN:
            k=k+1
            df.iloc[k,3] = df1.iloc[r,c]
        else:
            print("Nan Detected")
            l=l+1
print(l," Nan Values encountered")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check for NaN in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944700/how-to-check-for-nan-in-python)

Comment: I need to use this comparison in an If statement.
How would you use math.isnan in an if statement for comparison with a value...
for example:
for i in range(len(df)):
    for j in range(8):
        if math.isnan(df1.iloc[i,j]) == FALSE:
            b=b+1
            print(b ," correct out of", b+c)
        else:
            print("Error") 
I get error at line where If statement begins. 
Type Error: a float is required.

Comment: Then what is the type for `df1.iloc[i,j]`? Try insert `print(type(df1.iloc[r, c]))` between last for and the if.

Comment: It's numpy, float64

Comment: Try `numpy.isnan(x)` then, I don't use numpy, but that is covered in the link I previously gave.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately NaN will compare false, even with itself. So `df1.iloc[r,c] != NaN` is always true.

Use `numpy.isnan(number)` or `math.isnan(number)` instead to check if `number` is NaN.

Comment: for i in range(len(df)):
    for j in range(8):
        if math.isnan(df1.iloc[i,j]) == FALSE:
            b=b+1
            print(b ," correct out of", b+c)

        else:
            print("Error") 
The Error I get is at if statement. 
Type Error : a float is required.