# How to remove nan values from a dictionaries list of values in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

Hi I have a list of dictionaries, each dictionary has a list of values. In that list there are `nan` values which I wish to remove. Here is an example dictionary;

```
temp = {'A': ['field1', 'field2', 'field3', np.nan, np.nan], 'B': ['field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4', np.nan]}
```

which looks like;

```
{'A': ['field1', 'field2', 'field3', nan, nan], 'B': ['field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4', nan]}
```

I desired output is :

```
{'A': ['field1', 'field2', 'field3'], 'B': ['field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4']}
```

I've tired the following with no success;

```
res = {k:v for k,v in temp2.items() if v is not np.nan}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check for NaN in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944700/how-can-i-check-for-nan-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are comparing the whole value (v in your case) with np.nan, but only single elements of the value of the dictionary are np.nan.
You want:

```
res = {k:[elem for elem in v if elem is not np.nan] for k,v in temp.items()}
```

Comment: You could also use the [`numpy.isnan`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) method.