# Fill missing value

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-science

I have a data sets which has column with missing value 2439.
But the missing value is such that for specific index has some missing value and some fill value as shown below (Compare column 'Item_Identifier' and 'Item_Weight')

[image]

If carefully seen for specific item_identifier, there missing value in item_weight. Like this there many more Item_Identifier which missing value. Is there any way using python we fill missing value for only item_weight as same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check for NaN in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944700/how-can-i-check-for-nan-in-python)

Comment: 1)data_1[data_1['Item_Weight'].isnull()]      # Try this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the table into a pandas DataFrame then `df['item_weight'].fillna(15.5, inplace=True)`

Comment: He doesn't want it to be 0

Comment: Sorry, he can fill it with any value.

Comment: What if OP has 100 columns? He will look for each value manually and use this?

Comment: what should be solution when there are more then one type of 'item_weight' and each have some missing value?

Answer (score 0):

Reproducible example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'a', 'b','b', 'b', 'c'], 
                   'col2': [10, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 20, 30]})

    col1    col2
0   a       10.0
1   a       NaN
2   b       NaN
3   b       NaN
4   b       20.0
5   c       30.0
```

You can groupby your `col1` and `agg` using `first`

```
vals = df.groupby('col1').agg('first')

    col2
col1    
a   10.0
b   20.0
c   30.0
```

Then just use same indexing and `fillna()` to match and fill the values

```
df = df.set_index('col1').fillna(vals).reset_index()

    col1    col2
0   a       10.0
1   a       10.0
2   b       20.0
3   b       20.0
4   b       20.0
5   c       30.0
```