# Getting nan using row function. However while comparing row with nan, condition is getting False

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is the output of half expression mentioned in the last:

```
row['dep']
Out[302]: nan
```

However I am not getting BU in the cell 17,5.

```
if row['dep'] == 'nan':
     local.Cells(17,5).Value = "BU"
```

Can anyone please help

Comment: Use type method to find if both the types are same

Answer (score 1):

When you say `'nan'` in your code, you are creating a string containing the letters 'n', 'a' and 'n'. The semantic value `nan` is not represented as a string in Python. You can get `nan` as `float('nan')`.

Since `nan` is a special value and not a number (that's what NaN literally stands for, by the way), you cannot use `==` for comparison.

```
>>> float('nan') == float('nan')
```

will return `False`.

For checking if a variable is `nan`, it is best to use [math.isnan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944700/how-can-i-check-for-nan-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

`By definition`, `NaN` fails *any* value comparison.  The operation `== NaN` will return `False` regardless of what's on the left side.  `NaN == NaN` is `False`.

Instead, use the provided operator for this very purpose:

```
if isnan(row['dep']):
     local.Cells(17,5).Value = "BU"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement evaluates to False hence further part is not executed. This is because `nan == nan` evaluates to False as nan (not a number) is not defined and you cannot compare things which are not defined. Try changing your logic or using `isna()`, `fillna()` function.