# Replace Nan with coefficient for last number?

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
[1, 3 ,5, 7, NaN, NaN, NaN, 15, NaN]
```

I also have growth rate, let’s say it is : 0.5 .

I want my list to be filled with last number before NaN multiplied by 0.5 + 1. It’s is basically ffil * 1.5. But I don’t understand how to turn that into python code.

Can someone help?

Comment: [1, 3, 5, 7, 10.5, 15,75, 23.625, 15, 22,5]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
import math
data = [1, 3 ,5, 7, float("NaN"), float("NaN"), float("NaN"), 15, float("NaN")]

growRate = 0.5

for i in range(len(data)):
    if math.isnan(float(data[i])):
        data[i] = data[i-1] * (growRate + 1)

print(data)
```

Comment: `Nan` is a valid `float` value, so `float('NaN') == "NaN"` → `False`. Otherwise I think you have the right idea.

Comment: In a list you can't have letters without "", so I think that's the problem, or do you need to calculate the grow rate based on the Nan, or the difference between Nan and 7 in this case?

Comment: We don't know the list was created as a source code literal. It might have been calculated at execution time. In general you could have a list of values with one or more having a `float` value of `Nan`. For example: `['a', 42, 3.14,  float("NaN")]` → `['a', 42, 3.14, nan]`. Not that the `nan` at the end does not have quotes around it and isn't a string.

Comment: I didn't know about that, so then in this case `['a', 42, 3.14, nan]` you need to calculate the value of nan as a float?

Comment: Not sure I understand your last comment. What I mean is your code should be `if data[i] == float("NaN"):` (and each "NaN" in `data` should be `float("NaN")` as well to create proper test values).

Comment: Sorry for my English it's not my native language but I'm trying. Ok I understand you now.

Comment: No worries—your Python language skills seen quite good. `;¬)`. Fix your answer and I'll upvote it. Note you could also use `if math.isnan(data[i]):`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you going through [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) first.

For your answer:

```
import math
NaN = float('nan')
growth_rate = 1.5
list_ = [1,3,5,7,NaN,NaN,NaN,15,NaN]
for i in range(0,len(list_)):
  if( math.isnan( list_[i] ) ): # True if list_[i] is NaN .
    list_[i] = growth_rate * list_[i-1]
for i in list_:
  print i ,
```

[How can I check for NaN in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944700/how-can-i-check-for-nan-in-python)

Comment: It runs successfully! The conditional `if( math.isnan( float( list_[i] ) ) )`checks for `'nan'` after the element is casted to floating type as I think it should be.

Comment: Apparently you have fixed the problem since (and likely due to) my previous comment—so it now looks like it would work.