# how to determine if a tuple doesnt has an empty input Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, arraylist, tuples, nan

I'm simply trying to determine if my tuple has empty inputs. I'm reading Data from an Excel Sheet and it gives tuples in the form

```
(3,4,6), (3,4,7)
```

so basically it typically has 3 parameters but there are some cells that don't include the first or second parameter, so technically it would be

```
('','',6)
```

In my code I have set up as:

```
for i in range(len(self.listOfTuples)):
    for j in range(len(self.listOfTuples[i])):
        if(self.listOfTuples[i][j][0] == '' or self.listOfTuples[i][j][1] == ''):
            print("GOT IT ")
```

and it's not printing my statement, when I print out the `self.listofTuples[i][j][0]`. It actually prints out `nan`, but when I change my if statement with `"nan"` it still doesn't print out my statement. Is there something i'm missing ?

Comment: Any time you find yourself iterating over range(len(something)), you're doing it wrong. Iterate over the thing itself.

Comment: `None` and `nan` are _very different_ beasts. This question is not a dupe. It should be reopened.

Comment: Isn't the problem rather [checking for NaN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944700/how-can-i-check-for-nan-values)

Comment: @DYZ it is a common question

Comment: @W-B But not the one that you marked as a dupe.

Comment: yeah maybe so but the question that you linked to is a little different from what I asked. Plus I had already seen that post previously that's why I decided to post my own question

Comment: @DYZ 2nd link does not ?

Comment: @W-B The was no second link when I posted my comment.

Comment: @DYZ no worry , just take times to find the dup for me . :-)

Answer (score 1):

`nan` is "not-a-number". You can detect it with `math.isnan(self.listOfTuples[i][j][0])`.

Comment: so if the value is "nan" would it spit out true and if not false ?

Comment: Correct. And the `nan` that you see is actually `float("nan")`.

Comment: awesome it worked .