# How to see if during int casting its not an int

Tags: python, exception, casting

I have this `Matrix=[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', 'a', 'n']]`

Im doing this:

```
Matrix=[arr.split() for arr in Matrix]
Matrix=[list(map(int, arr)) for arr in Matrix]
```

as you can see I have 'a' and 'n' there, I want to stop the process and raise a flag like con=false everytime I got a char inside the Matrix,
how do I do that?

Comment: You can't. It's "buried" in the list comprehension. You'll need to go back to a `for` loop with a `try`/`except` and print the exceptional values.

Comment: can I have a snippet please?

Comment: I find it remarkably unlikely that you couldn't unpack your list comprehension here into a bog-standard `for` loop so I'm not sure what you're asking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to declare a "better" casting function and call it instead of `int` in `map`:

```py
matrix = [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', 'a', 'n']]

def int_with_default(value, default="NaN"):
    try: 
        return int(value)
    except ValueError: 
        return default

matrix = [list(map(int_with_default, arr)) for arr in matrix]
```

The output matrix will be `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 'NaN', 'NaN']]`. Note that you could also use [`math.nan`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/math.html#math.nan) instead of this arbitrary string I used as an example.

Comment: No reason to add `numpy` here;  https://stackoverflow.com/a/944733/4799172

Comment: I use numpy so often I wasn't even aware python had its own representation of `nan`. Now I'm wondering why numpy doesn't use this directly.

Comment: Because `math.isnan()` is a CPython function and would require calling all of that code to do the check. If `numpy` keeps its  own version of nan then it doesn't require CPython

Comment: I would like to hear more about this but I can't find anything that talks about that choice, do you have any ref? (Strangely `dir(math.nan) == dir(np.nan)` evaluate to `True`, but sadly `math.nan == np.nan` doesn't, luckily `math.isnan(np.nan)` evaluates to `True`.)

Comment: Well, `np.nan == np.nan` is also `False`. That's [by design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Comparison_with_NaN) hence the need for methods to identify `NaN` rather than check for equality. Your choice would be dictated by the libraries you are using and there is _no need_ to introduce `np.nan` here because the OP didn't say they were using it.

Comment: That makes sense indeed. I agree that there is point in using `np.nan` here, that's why I updated my suggestion as soon as you pointed out the existence of `math.nan`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only positive integers you can use the following listcomp:

```
m = [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', 'a', 'n']]

[list(map(lambda x: int(x) if x.isdigit() else None, row)) for row in m]
# [[1, 2, 3], [4, None, None]]
```