# The error is the following: ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Tags: python, pandas, date, type-conversion, integer

I have a column with datetime64[ns] values. So, in some cells in pandas, it has the value NaN when it is blank. I want to run the following function, but I am facing an error.

**The error is the following:ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer**

Here is the function I have:

```
def excel_date2(date1):
    temp = datetime(1899, 12, 30)   
    delta = date1 - temp
    return int(delta.days)
```

Here is where I am calling it in my project:

```
df['endedAtInteger'] = df['endedAt'].apply(excel_date2)
```

Here is an example of values the column has:

NaN

2018-09-02 15:20:15

2018-09-02 18:04:34

2018-09-02 18:11:15

2018-09-02 18:39:34

However, I do not want to permanently change the type of values of that column so in whatever you recommend please do it to another column. And I do not want to remove those values if possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check for NaN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944700/how-can-i-check-for-nan-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think converting to integers here is not necessary, if missing values all data are casted to floats:

```
def excel_date2(date1):
    temp = datetime(1899, 12, 30)   
    delta = date1 - temp
    return delta.days
```

But if need it is possible use [Nullable integer data type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html):

```
df['endedAtInteger'] = df['endedAt'].apply(excel_date2).astype('Int64')
```

Comment: can you check my latest question if you have some time thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59158082/loop-problem-indexerror-single-positional-indexer-is-out-of-bounds