# Apply function to column with null values and return NaN if null

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to apply a function convert_label() to a column CR_df['label'] of my dataframe. The outputs of the function are stored in a separate column CR_df['y']. However, my CR_df['label'] column has cells with NaN values. I want to apply my function only to cells in CR_df['label'] that don't have NaN values. If the cell does have an NaN value, I want to return NaN in the corresponding CR_df['y'] cell.

I don't want to check if I have NaN values, I need to return NaN if NaN.

My (error-prone) attempt at a solution

```
def convert_label(label):
    if "pos" in label:
        output = 1.0
    elif "neg" in label:
        output = 0.0
    else:
        output = label
    return output
```

I have tried to convert NaN to string and then applied my function but now I need to change all the string "nan" in CR_df['y'] to actual NaN or null values

```
CR_df['y'] = CR_df['label'].astype(str).apply(convert_label)
```

I've attached a picture of my output

[image]

Also, here is the code for my dataframe

```
    CR_train_file='data/custrev_train.tsv'
CR_test_file = 'data/custrev_test.tsv'


CR_train_df = pd.read_csv(CR_train_file, sep='\t', header=None)
CR_train_df.columns = ['index', 'label', 'review']
CR_test_df = pd.read_csv(CR_test_file, sep='\t', header=None)
CR_test_df.columns = ['index', 'review']
CR_test_df
CR_df = pd.concat([CR_train_df,CR_test_df], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check for NaN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944700/how-can-i-check-for-nan-values)

Comment: No, it doesn't. My question is how to return NaN values

Comment: Could you add an example for your dataframe?

Comment: Example of dataframe is provided above

Comment: Instead of a picture, you could post the code to generate such a dataframe, next time.

Comment: Sorry about that! I've attached the code now

Comment: You're checking for a `subtring in str` but is that necessary? Seems to be exact values given your example. Could you `df.label.map({'pos': 1, 'neg': 0}).fillna(df.label)` The `fillna` deals with anything that wasn't mapped and satisfies your condition of keeping `NaN` as `NaN`

Comment: Please share code/data as text in the post itself, not as images. I know you already accepted an answer, but I’m not satisfied with it, one reason being what @ALollz pointed out.

Comment: Also, what possible values can `label` and `y` take? I feel like at least `y` should be a boolean.

Comment: @ALollz The `fillna()` isn't even necessary in that case, if the value is not in the dictionary the result is `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `float` to assign a variable with `NaN`:

```
>>> import math
>>> a = float('nan')
>>> math.isnan(a)
True
>>> b = 'nan'
>>> math.isnan(b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: must be real number, not str
>>>
```

In the above, `a` got assigned an actual `NaN` value, while `b` just had a 'nan' string

Comment: is there a way to do this without looping through my dataframe? In addition, how would I apply the function directly and return NaN without having to convert everything to strings first?

Comment: @NingkaiZheng No to the first question. As for the second one, aren't the items already strings?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the currently accepted answer, which uses None for some reason, this does fulfill the condition *I don't want to check if I have NaN values, I need to return NaN if NaN.*

---

Hmm, we're mapping a what is essentially a binary variable (plus `NaN`, of course) to `0.0` or `1.0`. Sounds to me like we need some booleans™.

```py
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[('646', 'pos', 'bla bla 1'), ('2910', 'neg', 'bla bla 2'),
                          ('49', np.NaN, 'bla bla 3')], columns=['index_num', 'label', 'review'])

# accessing columns like civilized beings
df_1['y'] = df_1['label'].map({'pos': True, 'neg': False})
```

Before:

```
  index_num label     review
0       646   pos  bla bla 1
1      2910   neg  bla bla 2
2        49   NaN  bla bla 3
```

After:

```
  index_num label     review      y
0       646   pos  bla bla 1   True
1      2910   neg  bla bla 2  False
2        49   NaN  bla bla 3    NaN
```

---

Even if, hypothetically, we were to map to `0.0` or `1.0`, there's still no excuse for an `apply()` with an entire function.

Answer (score -1):

You could modify your function so that it checks for None. If you dont want to do that you could check for None (or NaN, depending on your needs) inside the apply call with a lambda function.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'label': [1, np.NaN, 'neg',[2], 
                         3, 'pos', 5, None,
                         np:NaN, 'test']})

def convert_label(label):
    if "pos" == label:
        return 1.0
    elif "neg" == label:
        return 0.0
    else:
        return label

df.label.apply(lambda x: convert_label(x) if x is not np.NaN else np.NaN)
>>>
0       1
1    None
2       0
3     [2]
4       3
5       1
6       5
7    None
8    None
9    test
Name: label, dtype: object
```

Or you use `DataFrame().where()`:

```
df.label.where(~df.label.isnull(), lambda x: convert_label(x))
```

Comment: Why use `None` when the question explicitly mentions `NaN`, the Pandas standard?

Comment: You can change it to NaN