# Nan check not recognizing Nan

Tags: python

I am using list comprehension to gather facebook links from a list of urls.

Here is the list:

```
list1 = ['facebook.com','johnsmithfacebook.com','amazon.com','google.com','stackoverflow.com']
```

Now I'll do list comprehension to grab the facebook urls, returning `np.nan` if nothing is found:

```
facebook = [i for i in list1 if 'facebook' in i] or pd.np.nan
```

And I'll join the strings if a result exists:

```
if facebook:
    facebook = ', '.join(facebook)

print(facebook)

'facebook.com, johnsmithfacebook.com'
```

Great. That works.

But if it there are no facebook urls, and `np.nan` is returned instead, I run into a problem:

```
# list
list2 = ['amazon','google']

facebook = [i for i in list2 if 'facebook' in i] or np.nan

if facebook: # nan check
    facebook = ', '.join(facebook) # join if not nan

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-1856f748f805> in <module>
      1 if facebook:
----> 2     facebook = ', '.join(facebook)

TypeError: can only join an iterable
```

The facebook variable is `nan`, so how did it get past the `if facebook:` check?

```
print(facebook)

nan
```

The error `can only join an iterable` sounds like I'm trying to join `None` or `Nan` from what I've read on google, but I tried to make sure `nans` didn't get past this point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check for NaN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944700/how-can-i-check-for-nan-values)

Comment: Bet your nan variable isn't a falsy value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `or np.nan` isn't needed at all, an empty array isn't truthy so it won't enter the if statement.

```
facebook = [i for i in list2 if 'facebook' in i]
```

On top of that, you don't even need the if statement since you'll just get an empty string if you try to join an empty list