# Is there any function in Python to check whether a value is "not is nan"

Tags: python, nan

There is a function in numpy named `np.isnan(A)` to check whether A is nan. In my case, A could be a number with some unknown value or `np.nan` returned from another function. I need a function to tell me whether A is nan or some number. I don't care the value of the number but I need to know if it is nan or not. I tried to use `!np.isnan(A)` but it's not a valid expression. Is there any function that can achieve this goal?

The structure of my code is like this:

```
if condition A and condition B:
    do something...
```

I need condition A to be some function that can fulfill the purpose of `!np.isnan(A)`.

Comment: `not np.isnan(A)`…?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check for NaN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944700/how-can-i-check-for-nan-values)