# Doesn't pandas recognize the np.nan value?

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to check if a variable is equal to np.nan in the code(4th last line). But somehow I don't get a desired output while doing this rather when I use np.nan with check condition it sort of ignores the statement itself, the code seems to run well for other values.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d={}
f=0
data=pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx')
for i in data[:]:
    d[i]=0
    f=0
    for j in data[i]:
        print(j)
        if j==np.nan:
            f=f+1
            d[i]=f
print(d)
```

Please tell if I'm doing something wrong, and how to resolve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check for NaN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944700/how-can-i-check-for-nan-values)

Comment: @LMc when I use this I get a Type error that says ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the inputs that could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ' ' safe ' '

Comment: Then try `pd.isnull`

Comment: @LMc still not working. Output is same as when I used np.nan.

Comment: Can you post some sample data that replicates the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Change the line `if j==np.nan:` to `if np.isnan(j):`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
if j==np.nan:
```

use

```
if np.isnan(j):
```