# how to convert a list of floats into integer. When there are NaN values in there! I got this lists from pandas dataframe which have some null values

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, nan

I'm trying to make a third list which is a intersection of 2 list(This lists I got from pandas dataframe). Now for list2 it is of float and first one is integer and now if I try to compare them third one will be empty one. I tried to convert list2 into integer but that's throwing an error for NaN ("cannot convert float NaN to integer"). Now how to convert that list2 into a list of integers?

Here's the snapshot of second list.[List2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDkO7.png)

And Here's my code:

```py
def intersection(lst1, lst2):
    lst3 = [value for value in lst1 if value in lst2]
    return lst3

list1_NY = df.New_york.values.tolist()
list2_NY = df.NY_11220.values.tolist()
list2_NY = [int(x) for x in list2_NY]
com_list_NY = intersection(list1_NY, list2_NY)
```

Comment: First you have to decide what you want to do with the NaN values.

Comment: Can you show the code you tried?

Comment: And not just NaN values. More generally, are you going to handle non-integer values with round, floor, or ceil? Clamp out-of-range values to INT_MIN and INT_MAX or treat them as invalid?

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not comment).

Comment: I want to remove all NaN values @Code-Apprentice .

Comment: @joanis here's code :'
def intersection(lst1, lst2):
    lst3 = [value for value in lst1 if value in lst2]
    return lst3

list1_NY = df.New_york.values.tolist()
list2_NY = df.NY_11220.values.tolist()
list2_NY = [int(x) for x in list2_NY]

com_list_NY = intersection(list1_NY, list2_NY)
'

Comment: Please edit the code into the question, using code block formatting, so we can read it.

Comment: I just answered your question, but it should probably be marked as a duplicate of [How can I check for NaN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/944700/3216427), which is where I found the `math.isnan(x)` solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check for NaN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944700/how-can-i-check-for-nan-values)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `math.isnan(x)` (see [How can I check for NaN values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/944700/3216427)) to detect and filter out the NaNs from list 2:

```
import math

def intersection(lst1, lst2):
    lst3 = [value for value in lst1 if value in lst2]
    return lst3

#list1_NY = df.New_york.values.tolist()
list1_NY = [123, 567]
#list2_NY = df.NY_11220.values.tolist()
list2_NY = [123.0, 234.0, float('NaN')]
list2_NY = [int(x) for x in list2_NY if not math.isnan(x)]
com_list_NY = intersection(list1_NY, list2_NY)

print(com_list_NY)
```

outputs `[123]`, which is correct given the values I hard-coded.