# Tensorflow NN: Custom loss and accuracy work, MSE returns NaN

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I've come into a bit of a confusing scenario. I'm training a Tensorflow/Keras neural network with a custom loss function and two metrics, MSE and accuracy. When evaluated on the training data, the loss and accuracy return numbers but the MSE is NaN. I was wondering if there was a possible explanation for this. Thanks.

Comment: my suggestions: 1- change your optimizer 2- check for nans in your input 3- normalize your input 4-in your target check if labels are correct (the range and etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Check your input again. The input may have some "Not a Number" values. Refer this: [How can I check for NaN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944700/how-can-i-check-for-nan-values)

Or a quick test:

```
for value in values:
    print(f"{repr(value):<8} : {is_nan(value)}")
```

Comment: Interesting - I'll try doing that. Thanks!

Comment: @Dammio How it is possible? MSE means the sum of the error^2 divided by the number of samples. the number of samples is always >0.

Comment: I modified my answer a bit, there may have some Not a Number exists.