# Change the value into number

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have dataset that the column is datetime type,
I have converted its column to object type for easier checking.
In this case, i want to check any column whatever the value are equal to 1, but if the column there are not any value or NaN are equal to 0. Example;

```
Year1.       |    Year.2     |    Year.3      |
12-01-2021         NaN              NaN
NaN             11-01-2021       12-02-2020
```

I want the result is:

```
Year1.       |    Year.2     |    Year.3      |
  1                 0               0
  0                 1               1
```

Anyone can help me to solve this case?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the values where you are not having `nan` as 1 using `df.where` and then fill `nan` with 0
try:

```
df = df.where(df.isna(),1).fillna(0)
```

---

**df:**

```
    Year1.  Year.2  Year.3
0   1       0       0
1   0       1       1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use either `math.isnan(x)`, `np.isnan(x)` or `pd.isna(x)` (depending on which library you're already using. Check each value of your table against one of these functions, and it will return 1 for a NaN, and 0 for a normal value.
[See related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944700/how-can-i-check-for-nan-values)