# how to check if any variable in Python is NaN?

Tags: python

I have like ~100 variables in my python code, Is there a way to check if anyone of the 100 variables is NaN, without having to check individual variables using isnan() ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check for NaN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944700/how-can-i-check-for-nan-values)

Comment: No human can maintain 100 variables.  You should be using a dictionary, in which case checking them en masse is a piece of cake.

Comment: *"I have like ~100 variables in my python code"* Then there might be room for optimization at this point already. Consider using lists or dictionaries and iterate over them.

Comment: That's a lot of variables to just coincidentally have to check all of them at the same time. Figure out how they're related, and store them in a list or dict instead of variables.

Comment: Assuming that you've stored them sensibly in a list/dict but you still don't want to test them all individually, you'd need some operation that would identify 1+ values of nan. I think adding them would do this. Example: `a = [1,3,float('nan')]` and then `sum(a)` would result in nan, indicating that at least one value was nan.

Answer (score 0):

Put the variables in a collection. If you always have the same set of named variables, a [named tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) is appropriate. Use the [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) iterator to check if any of the variables is NaN.

```
from math import isnan
from collections import namedtuple
MyData = namedtuple('MyData', ['foo', 'bar', 'qux'])
good_data = MyData(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
print(any(isnan(x) for x in good_data)) # False
bad_data = MyData(1.0, float('NaN'), 3.0)
any(isnan(x) for x in bad_data) # True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
a=1
b=-2
c=np.nan
d=3

Variables = np.array([a, b, c, d])

SumV = np.sum(Variables)
NanExistence = np.isnan(SumV)
NanExistence
```

Returns:

```
True
```

This Link describes the process:
https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-check-for-nan-elements-in-a-numpy-array-in-python

Answer (score -3):

It's in the link @rob provided, but I usually use.

```py
x != x
```

Not sure why you have 100 variables, but if you put them in a `dict`, it'd just be a matter of iterating through its values, checking each value.
Otherwise, there is always `eval()` if you somehow have a list of all your variables.

```py
ld = locals()
bad = []
for k, v in ld.items():
    if isinstance(v, float) and v != v:
        bad.append(k)

print("NaN Variables:", bad)
```

Comment: The question is not "how to I check a variable for NaN".  The question is "how can I check a hundred different variables without doing them one by one."

Comment: I downvoted when you added the `evil()`… sorry typo…`eval()` part.

Comment: I understand the point about `eval()`, and rarely use it myself -- but if they are saying "I have a 100 variables", I can't think of any reasonable way to deal with free variables of this sort, aside from using `locals()` or `globals()`, which is as evil as `eval()`, in my opinion. Maintaining more than a dozen variables is cause for headache.