# check for empty spaces & np.NaN in strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, numpy, nan

I wrote a function such that if the passed `val` only has whitespaces in it for example `'    '`, they all get removed and we return `np.Nan` or a `null`value.

```
def check_for_empty_spaces(val):
    val = val.rstrip()
    if len(val)<1:
        return np.NaN
    else:
        return val
        
print(len(check_for_empty_strings('WHAJS  ')))
print(check_for_empty_strings('WHAJS'))
print(check_for_empty_strings('  '))
print(check_for_empty_strings(''))
```

The function returns as desired. The output is:

```
5
WHAJS
nan
nan
```

but now when I use this function, I want to check that the string is

1. not just whitespaces
2. not NULL

However, when I check this:

```
check = check_for_empty_strings('')
if (check):
    print('tru')
    print(check)
else:
    print('dsj')
```

I get this output

```
tru
nan
```

Why is the first one tru? If check == NaN then shouldn't `if (check)` be False? How else can I check that my value is not just whitespaces or NULL.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/944733/11101156

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can check for `np.nan`:

```
np.isnan(check)
```

Or you can return `None` instead of `np.nan` and then check for it as you have done above in the if condition because `bool(None)` evaluates to `False`. If you evaluate `bool(np.nan)` on the other hand you get the output to be `True`.

Comment: Your snippet would not work if I check ```np.isnan('')```

Comment: Nah that's not what's required. I specifically want to check if my value is nan or not because I could also be testing with other strings like 'Jhdu  ' or 'dsd'

Comment: @x89 what do you want to tell me with your second to last comment?

Comment: I meant that if I check ```np.isnan('mystringvalue  ')``` or something like ```np.isnan('mystringvalue  ')==False```, it would throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

```
check = check_for_empty_strings('')
if (np.isnan(check)):
    print('tru')
    print(check)
else:
    print('dsj')
```

This works

Comment: Your snippet would not work if I check ```np.isnan('')```