# Null values present but not detected

Tags: python, pandas, null

In the following code, the column `df2['age_groups']` has definitely one null value.

I am trying to append this null value to a list, but this list turns out to be empty.

Why am I running into this problem?

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(100)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"ages": np.random.randint(10, 80, 20)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"ages": np.random.randint(10, 80, 20)})

df1['age_groups'], bins = pd.cut(df1["ages"], 4, retbins=True)
df2['age_groups'] = pd.cut(df2["ages"], bins=bins)
null_list=[]
for i in df2['age_groups']:
    if i == float('nan'):
        null_list.append(i)
print(null_list) #empty list
print(df2['age_groups'].isna().sum()) # it shows that there is one null value
```

and

```
 type(i) == float('nan')
```

generates the same outcome

Comment: Can't reproduce because of `name 'np' is not defined`

Comment: @AlejandroMartinez `np` is the usual abbreviation used for numpy. (fixed in code)

Answer (score 1):

For test missing values `NaN` and `None` (obviously same processing in pandas) is used [`pd.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.isna.html), not `is`, not `==`:

```
null_list=[]
for i in df2['age_groups']:
    if pd.isna(i):
        null_list.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to fix the `if` condition. See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944700/how-can-i-check-for-nan-values?rq=1).

Try this:

```
np.random.seed(100)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"ages": np.random.randint(10, 80, 20)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"ages": np.random.randint(10, 80, 20)})

df1['age_groups'], bins = pd.cut(df1["ages"], 4, retbins=True)
df2['age_groups'] = pd.cut(df2["ages"], bins=bins)


null_list=[]
for i in df2['age_groups']:
    if i is np.nan: # <- code changed here to np.nan
        null_list.append(i)
        
print(null_list) 
print(df2['age_groups'].isna().sum())
```

Output:

```
[nan]
1
```