# how to find $avg and $sum for fields which contain NaN value in mongodb?

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregate, pymongo, nan

I can find and limit columns which contain NaN value before using `$group` clause in mongodb when I use mongo cli or JavaScript. However, when I use python and its major library "pymongo" it seems not to be able to do the same. As following code NaN is not part of python syntax. Whereas it is easy and straight forward in javaScript. Any body has same problem?

#### javascript

```js
db.getCollection('plan.data_pool').aggregate([
                                     {'$match':{geoid:'00','v':{"$ne":NaN}}},{"$group":{"_id":"$accountable_id","agg":{"$sum":"$v"}}}

])
```

### python (pymongo)

```py
db['plan.data_pool'].aggregate([{'$match':{geoid:'00','v':{"$ne":NaN}}},
{"$group":{"_id":"$accountable_id","agg":{"$sum":"$v"}}}
```

##### sample document of `data_pool` collection is like this:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("619149fa0f91f1b3954f7128"),
    "opg" : "sum",
    "opt" : "sum",
    "code" : "9-8-1-1-1-7",
    "responsible" : [ 
        "61"
    ],
    "parent_id" : "610a6abb566701e77a214355",
    "accountable_id" : "59",
    "data_item" : "610a6c49566701e77a21435c",
    "geoid" : "HQ",
    "year" : 2019 ,
    "period" : "3M",
    "tf" : 3,
    "w" : 100.0,
    "p" : 6.0,
    "v" : NaN,
    "r" : 33.3333333333333,
    "plan" : "60d2ce9cc0b1f833dbd9563a"
}
```

Comment: can you share a sample document from `data_pool` collection? I think this is possible in python

Comment: I added a sample document into question.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944700/how-can-i-check-for-nan-values

Comment: @Joe unfortunately that is for checking a variable in python scope. In this issue we need to send condition through pymongo, in order to check it in mongodb.

Comment: NaN is defined by IEEE-754, did you try specifying it in python syntax instead of the javascript `NaN`?

Comment: @Joe . Indeed, pymongo trasforms python syntax into mongodb query language which is based on the JavaScript . e.g. it changes None to null, but there isn't same option to use instead of  NaN. My question is about pymongo not pure python.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: error is that NaN is not python syntax. so as Belly answered it was solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `NaN` value in MongoDB is represented by `float('NaN')` in pymongo, so you can use:

```
{'v': {'$ne': float('NaN')}}
```

Comment: It's a valuable answer. It works. bravo dear Belly and thank you very much.