# how to replace NaN using lambda

Tags: pandas

I have dataframe like this:

```py
dict={'priorSaleYear':[2004, np.NaN],'lastSaleYear':[2008, 2009]}
df=pd.DataFrame(dict, index=[1,2])
```

I want to replace the np.nan with the lastSaleYear minor a number:

```py
df['priorSaleYear']= df.apply (lambda row: (row['lastSaleYear'] - b) if row['priorSaleYear'] is np.nan else row['priorSaleYear'], axis=1)
```

But it seems like row['priorSaleYear'] is np.nan not work, can someone help me, thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check for NaN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944700/how-can-i-check-for-nan-values)

Answer (score 0):

You did not clarify if there are more than one continuous `NaN` how the fill should be. Here, I assume that for all `NaN`, they will use the most recent available value.

```
df['priorSaleYear'] = df['priorSaleYear'].ffill()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `fillna()` and state with what you want to fill it:

```
df['priorSaleYear']=df.priorSaleYear.fillna(df.lastSaleYear-1337)

>>> df
   priorSaleYear  lastSaleYear
1         2004.0          2008
2          672.0          2009
```