# Why can't I use the == operator when comparing to "NaN"?

Tags: python, numpy

Trying to get my head around this...

```
a = float("NaN")

a == float("NaN")
```

Out: False

```
np.isnan(a)
```

Out: True

Comment: Because `NaN` is not equal to anything, including itself. By definition.

Comment: NaN is effectively a null value: https://wiki.dataself.com/NULL_Values

Comment: Related post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944700/

Comment: There are really many different not-a-number values, `float("NanN")` just produces one of them. One of the more significant consequences of using inband signaling of errors is that floating-point equality is *not* an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation), because reflexivity is not respected.

Answer (score 0):

"NaN" means that it isn't equal to anything. So {thing1 which is NaN} == {thing2 which is NaN} will always be "False" because NaN is not equal to anything, including itself.

Comment: There is no point to *repeat* other comments here.   Even better is to include some more related reference..to make it complete.

Comment: Didn't see that, my bad! Thanks